# Android studio error when add java8 support

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-jack-and-jill

what's wrong with my Android Studio or my config?

```
Error:(22, 0) Could not find method jackOptions() for arguments [build_1b0umrzpkhcolzr325bxbizec$_run_closure1$_closure5@41c39fc1] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

and this is my build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.twtstudio.wepeiyanglite"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I guess the jack is not enabled in my develop enviroment , and how to find out the mistakes and fix it?
I have already installed the jdk1.8

Comment: Move the jackOptions inside your defaultConfig and Sync project

Comment: I follow your tips and  edited  apt and classpath settings,it works,thank you!

Answer (score 32):

jackOptions should be inside defaultConfig{} like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support?utm_source=android-studio):**

**The Jack toolchain is deprecated**, as per this [announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html). If your project depends on Jack, you should migrate to using Java 8 support built into Android Studio’s default toolchain. Using the default toolchain also includes support for third-party libraries that use Java 8 language features, [Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run), and tools that depend on intermediate .class files.

To disable Jack and switch to the default toolchain, simply remove the jackOptions block from your module’s build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        // Remove this block.
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
            ...
        }
    }

    // Keep the following configuration in order to target Java 8.
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to latest documentation

```
defaultConfig {
  ...
  jackOptions {
    enabled true
  }
}
```

is redundant, so you can remove that entirely.

Please refer https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html?utm_source=android-studio

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compileOpitons` after `buildTypes` block without using `jackOptions` block like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abdo.nadias"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add `jackOptions` if you are not migrating from `jackOptions`.

Refere this link:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/java-8-for-android-cleaner-code-with-lambda-expressions--cms-29661

Answer (score 0):

move :

```
 jackOptions {
              enabled true
}
```

inside `default config { }` parenthesis