# Could not find method jackOptions() for arguments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Hi everyone I'm facing the

> Could not find method jackOptions() for arguments [build_ccqj3loj50621uihss8xz3wml$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure6@24055137] on DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=16, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=25, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=1, versionName=1.0, applicationId=com.vpaliy.flip_concept, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.

issue when I'm trying to clone [this](https://github.com/vpaliyX/LoginConcept) repo from Github. I have tried the official doc [disable jack](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#disable_jack) and also checked SO [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944593/android-studio-error-when-add-java8-support), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880115/how-to-enable-jack-java-android-compiler-kit-in-android-studio) but they weren't of much help as I tried to remove the

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

from the gradle as per the official doc but still the error persists and also tried to invalidate cache and restart but nothing there either. Any help is much appreciated

module level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vpaliy.loginconcept"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.Q42:AndroidScrollingImageView:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

project level gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
      google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Moving forward, Java 8 language features will be natively supported by the Android build system.

Well I found that I was committing a silly mistake of not removing the below code

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

from the [flip-concept's](https://github.com/vpaliyX/LoginConcept/blob/master/flip-concept/build.gradle) `build.gradle` file as well due to which I wasn't able to build and run the project. After removing it I'm able to run the project

Comment: Why do we need to remove this bolck from build.gradle ?

Comment: Because Jack is now deprecated, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill

Comment: "Moving forward, Java 8 language features will be natively supported by the Android build system."

Comment: Awesome findings. Upgrading my gradle to use java 8 and remove jackOptions works for me.