# `Could not find method jackOptions() for arguments` when building Tensorflow Lite demo

Tags: android, tensorflow

I'm trying to build the demo app in Tensorflow Lite:

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/demo_android

Relevant versions:

- Tensorlow Lite: 1.12
- Android Studio: 3.2.1
- Android Sdk: android-28

When I try to make the project included at `tensorflow/lite/java/demo` I get a build error:

```
Could not find method jackOptions() for arguments
```

Presumably this relates to `Jack and Jill` being deprecated as noted in this related SO article: [Could not find method jackOptions() for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941319/could-not-find-method-jackoptions-for-arguments).

However I'm unclear how it's being used in the Tensorflow demo. My best guess is that using an older version of the SDK might be a temporary solution, so if anyone knows what versions of the various APIs/SDKs will build successfully I would love to know. Or if there's another solution I might apply.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can pass this build error by commenting out lines 15, 16, 17 in `tensorflow/lite/java/demo/app/build.gradle` in the demo app provided in the demo source.

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

This moved me onto another build error at least. I may update this later if there are more relevant details.